# Finding the highest occurrence of a Physician based on how many patients in each City

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to create an aggregation query that will display the physician that has the most patients in each City. That also works with the average age for each city.

For example:

```
{
     City: "Vancouver"
     Physician: "Physician Test1"
     Average_Age: 56
},
{
     City: "Burnaby"
     Physician: "Physician Test2"
     Average_Age: 40
}
```

Example of some of my data

```
{
        "gender" : "Female",
        "full_name" : "Test Patient",
        "age" : 20,
        "city" : "Burnaby",
        "severity_code" : 2,
        "PHN" : "11-1111111",
        "primary_physician" : "Physician Test1",
        "location" : "4A",
        "attendance_method" : "Self-Driven"
},
{
        "gender" : "Male",
        "full_name" : "Test2 Patient2",
        "age" : 68,
        "city" : "Vancouver",
        "severity_code" : 1,
        "PHN" : "00-0000000",
        "primary_physician" : "Physician Test2",
        "location" : "6D",
        "attendance_method" : "Walk-In"
 }
```

How do I create the aggregation query for the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.patients.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "City": "$city",
                "Physician": "$primary_physician"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "Average_Age": { "$avg": "$age" }               
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.City"
            "Physician": { "$first": "$_id.Physician" },
            "Number_of_Patients": { "$first": "$count" },
            "Average_Age": { "$first": "$Average_Age" }         
        }
    }   
])
```

In the above aggregation, the first pipeline step with the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator groups the documents by the `city` and `physician` fields and calculates the number of documents (thus the number of patients) in the group through the [`{ "$sum": 1 }`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) expression, as well as aggregating the avarage age of the patients with [`{ "$avg": "$age" }`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) expression.

The second pipeline stage [`{ "$sort": { "count": -1 } }`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) orders the previously grouped documents by the count. This is necessary for the further grouping since you want to get the `physician` that has the most patients in each `city` i.e. in the each group, take the top document that has the largest count. The preceding pipeline does excactly this.

It groups the sorted documents by the `city` key and then returns the  desired fields using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator.

Comment: I'm confused on the $sort: { count: -1}} on the query you provided. How does that work with this aggregation?

Comment: The pipeline stage with `{ "$sort": { "count": -1 } }` orders the previously grouped documents by the count (occurrence). This is necessary for the further grouping since you want to get the physician that has the most patients in each city i.e. in the each group, take the top document that has the largest count. The preceding pipeline does excactly this.